# Creating multiple files for each tld and sorting each file

Tags: perl, tld

I've a listing of million web addresses. I have to extract the TLD for every url and make multiple files for every TLD. For instance collect all web addresses with .com as tld and dump that in 1 file, another apply for .edu tld and so forth. Further within each file, I must sort it alphabetically by domain names after which by subdomains etc.
ct
Can anybody produce a jump for applying this in perl?

I have used the URI module to extract the tld and domain and host names for each web address.
How do I collect all web addresses with com tld and dump them in 1 file?
And how to go about sorting each file by tld , then by domain then by subdomain etc?
Any pointers?

```
while(my $line = <$fh1>){   

my $url = $line;

 my @components =  split(/\./, $url);
 my $n_comp = ($components[-1] =~ /^edu|com|net|org|gov$/) ? 2 : 3;
 my $domain = lc(join '.', @components[-$n_comp .. -1]);
 $domain =~ s/^\.//;  # Remove leading . if there is one.
 print $fh3 $domain;
        print $fh3 "\n";


  my $host = URI->new($url)->host();

 # Treat relative URLs as absolute URLs with missing http://.
 $url = "http://$url" if $url !~ /^\w+:/;



 $host =~ s/\.\z//;  # D::PS doesn't handle "domain.com.".
 print $fh2 $host;
 print $fh2 "\n";
 $dps->get_root_domain($host)
 or die $dps->error();
 print $fh4 $dps->tld();
 print $fh4 "\n";


 }
```

Comment: Does the output have to have a specific format? Does it have to be easily readable by Humans/Computers?

Comment: Splitting the domain in it's components is the right start. Now you have to write a comparison function which compares two component-arrays starting from the TLD down to the subdomains. The biggest roadblock would be the handling of component-arrays with different lengths.

Comment: @BradGilbert Yes It has to be in human readable format... the thing is a domain can have multiple Ip's and eaxh domain can have multiple nameservers and each nameserver multiple IP's, how do I output this in a file in perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $input, '<', shift @ARGV;
my %domain;
while( <$input> ){
  chomp;
  #                                   (  protocol   ) (  domain ) (rest)
  my ($protocol,$domain,$remain) = /^ (?:(\w+):\/\/)? ([^\\\/#]+) ( .* ) /x;

  my ($tld,@domain) = reverse split /[.]/, $domain;

  my $cmp = join '.', @domain;
  push @{ $domain{$tld} }, [ $cmp, $remain, $_ ];
}
close $input;

while( my($tld,$list) = each %domain ){
  open my $out, '>', $tld;
  print {$out} "$_\n" for map{
    $_->[-1]
  }sort{
    $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] ||
    $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] ||
    $a->[2] cmp $b->[2]
  } @$list;
  close $out;
}
```

---

1. First we break the input into the parts we need.

   ```
   /^ (?:(\w+):\/\/)? ([^\\\/#]+) ( .* ) /x;
   ```

   - This will match an optional `http://` or similar.

     ```
     (?:(\w+):\/\/)?
     ```
   - This matches anything except `\`, `/`, and `#`, since those are the characters that usually come after the domain.

     ```
     ([^\\\/#]+)
     ```
   - This of course matches whatever remains.

     ```
     ( . )
     ```
2. We want to sort the URLs from the top level domain, down to the lowest level domain. So we [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the domain, and [reverse](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) it.

   ```
   my ($tld,@domain) = reverse split /[.]/, $domain;
   ```
3. To compare two URLs we want a string that is simple to compare.

   ```
   my $cmp = join '.', @domain;
   ```
4. Store the information for later.

   ```
   push @{ $domain{$tld} }, [ $cmp, $remain, $_ ];
   ```
5. [Open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) the file we're going to print to.

   ```
   while( my($tld,$list) = each %domain ){
     open my $out, '>', $tld;
   ```
6. [Sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) the list of URLs that are going into the current file.

   ```
   ...
   sort{
     $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] ||
     $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] ||
     $a->[2] cmp $b->[2]
   } @$list;
   ```
7. [Map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) the list to the actual URL.

   ```
   ...
   map{
     $_->[-1]
   }
   ...
   ```
8. [Print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) to the file each URL in the list.

   ```
   print {$out} "$_\n" for ...
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot @BradGilbert for comprehensive explanation!
Can you tell me what exactly happens here : push @{ $domain{$tld} }, [ $cmp, $remain, $_ ];